# Differential Calculus: How to find the slope of the curve $y=x(x+1)(x+2)$ at the points where it crosses the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

Find the slope of the curve $y=x(x+1)(x+2)$ at the points where it crosses the $x$-axis.

Comment: The curve crosses the x axis at $x = 0,-1,2$. Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and evaluate it at these points.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  For instance, have you found the derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = x(x+1)(x+2)$

First: where does it cross the $x$-axis? When $y=0.$

$0=x(x+1)(x+2) \implies x=\{0,-1,-2\}$

Now the slope at each point of the curve is given by: $\dfrac{dy}{dy} = 3x^2+6x+2$

So slopes are: $\{2,-1,2\}$ respectively.